# Using Filter property of PrimeReact DataTable

Tags: reactjs, primereact

One of the columns of the DataTable implemented is somewhat like this

```
{ field: 'FieldValuesAsText#XYZ', header: 'XYZ', width: '150px', sort: true, filterElement: 'No' }

<Column key={col.field} 
        field={col.field} 
        header={col.header}
        body={this.trimContent}
        filter={true}
        filterMatchMode="contains"
        sortable={col.sort}/>
```

The **FieldValuesAsText** is a object with **XYZ** as one of it's attribute. The custom function used in the **body** property successfully retrieves the value but the problem is when I try to do the filter operation. Since the **filter** defaults to field which in this case is **FieldValuesAsText#XYZ**, so it is obviously going to return undefined. How will I be able to make my filter properly work?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom filter function.
Here is a custom function that I have used to filter a similar column in my Datatable.

```
filterMatchMode="custom" filterFunction={customFunction}


export const customFunction = (value, filter) => {
  return value.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) >= 0
}
```

Comment: what is value and filter parameters here? Is this automatically detects by the Prime React or you need to pass a data here?

Comment: if i remember correctly `value` is the value of the column and filter is the typed search string.